# Por que geralmente os nomes de arquivos não levam caracteres especiais?

Tags: sistema-de-arquivos, convenções-de-nome, convenções

É comum que os nomes de arquivos sigam padrões como `nome-imagem.jpeg` (em minúsculo e separado por hífens). Essa prática é adotada por convenção ou por causa de compatibilidade com servidores web?

Essa dúvida é em relação a nomes de arquivos utilizados em projetos web, por exemplo, um arquivo CSS geralmente é chamado de `estilo-padrao.css` ou `estilo_padrao.css`, mas não de `estilo padrão.css`. A mesma dúvida serve para arquivos de imagem, javascript e arquivos de configuração (como JSON, por exemplo) para back-end.

Comment: Por comparatibilidade de tipos de formatos de partições de HDs e limites de sistemas operacionais antigos. Fora a notável simplificação da URL, que ao invés de ficar com algo como `nome%20imagem.jpg`, que é bem mais dificil de digitar (`%20` equivale a um espaço), ainda o NÃO uso de acentos ajuda a facilitar a digitação em teclados que não fornecem isso de forma fácil, os teclados inglês internacional e ABNT tem acentos, mas outras variações não terão todos acentos do português e o mesmo vale para outros idiomas. Então manter dentro do ASCII será com certeza mais fácil

Comment: ps: o downvote não é meu, eu ia formular a resposta mais detalhada, mas estou sem tempo agora.